# An alternative to if/else for handling Earth Engine App selector options

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm building an Earth Engine App that has a drop down selector. When a user selects an option from the menu a function performs a task with variable values specific to the selected option. Currently, I use a series of if/else statements to define the variable values used in the function i.e. if a user selects "Option 1", then use these variable values. Is there a different/better way to achieve dynamic variable value assignment than if/else statements?

Here is a representation in JS API code:

```js
var options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'];

var selectMenu = ui.Select(options);
print(selectMenu);

function printOptionVars(option) {
  var a; 
  var b;
  var c;
  if (option == 'Option 1') {
    a = 'option 1 string';
    b = 1;
    c = ee.DateRange('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01');
  } else if (option == 'Option 2') {
    a = 'option 2 string';
    b = 2;
    c = ee.DateRange('2015-01-01', '2016-01-01');
  } else if (option == 'Option 3') {
    a = 'option 3 string';
    b = 3;
    c = ee.DateRange('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01');
  }
  
  print(a);   
  print(b);
  print(c);
}

selectMenu.onChange(printOptionVars);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary with a set of nested dictionaries, one for each option. The first level key names are the drop selection option names and each respective dictionary holds the relevant variable values. When a user selects an option from the drop menu, use the option name to fetch the corresponding dictionary of values needed.

Here is the same example using a dictionary instead of if/else:

```js
// Hard code variables per desired drop down menu option.
// 1st level key names will be the option names in the
// drop down menu.
var dataInfo = {
  'Option 1': {
    'var a': 'option 1 string',
    'var b': 1,
    'var c': ee.DateRange('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01')
  },
  'Option 2': {
    'var a': 'option 2 string',
    'var b': 2,
    'var c': ee.DateRange('2015-01-01', '2016-01-01')
  },
  'Option 3': {
    'var a': 'option 3 string',
    'var b': 3,
    'var c': ee.DateRange('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01')
  }
};

// Populate drop down selector using 1st level keys.
var selectMenu = ui.Select(Object.keys(dataInfo));
print(selectMenu);

// Define a callback function that fires when a selection
// from the drop menu is made. 
function printOptionVars(option) {
  // Extract the variable dictionary for the selected option.
  var selectedOption = dataInfo[option];
  // Extract variables for the selected option as needed from
  // the selected option's dictionary.
  print(selectedOption['var a']);   
  print(selectedOption['var b']);
  print(selectedOption['var c']);
}

// Register the callback with the selector's on change event. 
selectMenu.onChange(printOptionVars);
```